# Adding programs to run off cd

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I want to run Ubuntu from a cd and add a set of custom programs to the cd so they will be there each time I boot. How do I accomplish this?